# TeamCity deploy previous build

Tags: github, deployment, build, version, teamcity

Is it possible for TeamCity deploy config to deploy build version before most recent ?

My source code is on GitHub and I have a TC pipeline consisting of a build config and a deploy config.

On creation of PR, that branch is built ( but not deployed ).

On merge PR to master, master branch is built.

Deploy config only deploys builds of master branch and is triggered by successful build of master branch.

For troubleshooting purposes, I'd like to deploy a previous master build.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how your build is setup. If the deploy config content is also in source control, then you can try tagging the master branch revision you want and giving teamcity that tag as your branch input to build when you trigger the deploy build. If you have a snapshot dependency on that deploy build, then it will queue the build it depends on with the same branch input parameter except it finds a suitable build (if you configure it to use a suitable build).